# Error installing virtualenv Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am installing virtualenv using the following command

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and this is what is got:

```
C:\Users\X>pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\req\req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\req\req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\wheel.py", line 493, in move_wheel_files
    maker.make_multiple(['%s = %s' % kv for kv in console.items()])
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 383, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 212, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 351, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
  File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 324, in finder
    raise DistlibException('Unable to locate finder for %r' % package)
pip._vendor.distlib.DistlibException: Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.d
istlib'
```

BTW i am using python 3.6. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in pip under windows.

The following steps helped me solve the problem:
1. uninstall pip:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

2. reinstall pip  with [this script][1].
3. run get-pip.py from within your venv

This should solve it.